# Selenium webdriver can't find xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation, automated-tests

[image]

element code:

```
<div class="col col-2"><div class="v-input v-input--is-focused theme--light v-text-field v-text-field--is-booted v-select primary--text"><div class="v-input__control"><div role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="list-65" class="v-input__slot"><div class="v-select__slot"><label for="input-65" class="v-label v-label--active theme--light primary--text" style="left: 0px; right: auto; position: absolute;">Narystė</label><div class="v-select__selections"><input id="input-65" readonly="readonly" type="text" aria-readonly="false" autocomplete="off"></div><div class="v-input__append-inner"><div class="v-input__icon v-input__icon--append"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate material-icons theme--light primary--text">arrow_drop_down</i></div></div><input type="hidden" value="[object Object]"></div><div class="v-menu"><!----></div></div><div class="v-text-field__details"><div class="v-messages theme--light primary--text"><div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

in screen you can see, that entered xpath is only one.

Here is code, where i have entered the same xpath, but getting error like this:

```
 private static final By naryste = By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'v-label v-label--active theme--light primary--text') and contains(text(),'Narystė')]");
    @Step("Pasirenkame juridinio asmens organizaciją iš reikšmių sąrašo")
    public createOrganization selectMembership() {
        button.click(naryste);
        return this;
    }
```

Selenium webdriver can't find this xpath:

```
Find element :By.xpath: //*[contains(@class,'v-label v-label--active theme--light primary--text') and contains(text(),'Narystė')]
```

**P.S. the same problem if i choose other elements**
[image]

AND this (selenium can't find)

[image]

Comment: Instead of an image can you update the question with the text based HTML of the element?

Comment: i have added element code, idk if it helps you, code is inline..

Comment: Refers to a _`readonly`_ element, are you sure the element is interactable?

Comment: css classes aren't always unique... I'd just use the text()= part there.  (Unless something else on the page is labeled "Narystė".  Still you'd want to target something besides the label.  Maybe use //div[@aria-owns="list-65"] or //input[@id="input-65"] ?  depends on what takes the click event?  (Not sure what button.click() method is in your code...)

Comment: @pcalkins, id input-XX is generate dinamically after refresh.

Comment: @DebanjanB, i'm not sure, maybe i should choose other element in this div and i tryied, but result is the same. I

Comment: You need to use a webdriverwait for any JS added components:  https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  By.xpath("//label[starts-with(@for,'input') and contains(.,'Narystė')]");
  ```

PS: Do add some [waits](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) before invoking the `click()`

Comment: `org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted:`

Comment: The reason I questioned about _`readonly`_ attribute :)

Comment: how can i solve that..?

Comment: i get the same error if i choose other element path. Added image i P.S.